# Laravel 5.4 Mix & webpack CPU issue

Tags: laravel, webpack, webpack-2, laravel-mix

Hi all i have a fresh install of Laravel 5.4,
when run `npm run dev`cpu working a lot, 200%.

I need to "watch" my asset file changes,i run `npm run watch`, didn't work. 
i use vagrant (virtualbox) on mac and i read on webpack doc that in this environment i need to use `npm run watch-poll`, it works but my CPU work at 200% during watches.

I try to set `ignore: '/node_modules/'` on my webpack.config.js but seems not work.

any ideas?

Thx all

Answer (score 1):

Go into `/node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js` and find the `ignored` option. Set it to `/node_modules/`, no quote marks. So far this has been my solution.